# How to make this square gone in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was trying to make this square around the text gone, but I couldn't figure out how.
[image]

I tried to make the background color of the text the same as the window background, but it didn't work. Please help.

Here's my code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime as dt

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg="#af8d86")
root.title("Digital Clock")

title_label = ttk.Label(
    root,
    text="Digital Clock",
    font=("Segoe UI", 25),
    justify="center",
)
title_label.pack(pady=60)

def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl.config(text = string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)
 

lbl = ttk.Label(
    root, 
    font = ('Segoe UI', 40),
    justify="center"
    )
lbl.pack(pady=20)



date = dt.now()
date_label = ttk.Label(
    root,
    text=f"{date:%A, %B, %d, %y}",
    font=("Segoe UI", 20)
)
date_label.pack(pady=30)

time()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tk.Label` with the same background color as the underlying `Frame`:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from time import strftime
from datetime import datetime as dt

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
root.resizable(False, False)
root.configure(bg="#af8d86")
root.title("Digital Clock")

title_label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text="Digital Clock",
    font=("Segoe UI", 25),
    justify="center",
    bg="#af8d86"
)
title_label.pack(pady=60)

def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl.config(text = string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)
 

lbl = tk.Label(
    root, 
    font = ('Segoe UI', 40),
    justify="center",
    bg="#af8d86"
    )
lbl.pack(pady=20)



date = dt.now()
date_label = tk.Label(
    root,
    text=f"{date:%A, %B, %d, %y}",
    font=("Segoe UI", 20),
    bg="#af8d86"
)
date_label.pack(pady=30)

time()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used `ttk.Label`, you can change the label background color using `ttk.Style.configure()`:

```py
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabel', background='#af8d86')
```

Comment: I tried this one as well and it also worked! Thank you so much!